# The Lie algebra of Harmonic functions

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry

Is there a Riemannian metric $g$ on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ with  corresponding  volume form $\omega= \sqrt{det(g_{ij})} dx \wedge dy$ and the   corresponding Laplace operator $\Delta$  such that the  space of $\Delta$- harmonic  functions would be  closed under the Poisson bracket arising from the symplectic  form $\omega$?

Comment: No, this does not exist, as you can tell by using the fact that the $\Delta$-harmonic functions depend only on the conformal structure, which you can assume to be the standard one.  I.e., you can assume that the metric is of the form $g = \lambda(x,y)(\mathrm{d}x^2+\mathrm{d}y^2)$.  Then the $\Delta$-harmonic functions $u(x,y)$ are just the harmonic functions in the usual sense, i.e., $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$, and you can now check that there is no nonzero $\lambda(x,y)$ that yields the property you want.

Comment: @RobertBryant  Thank you very  much for your comment. What  about if  we replace the plane  by an arbitrary   orientable  2 manifold?Moreover, in order to generalize to $2n$  dimension, assume that $\Omega$ is  the  volume  form  associated with the metric $g$. Is there a symplectic two form $\omega$ on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$  such that $\omega^{n}=\Omega$?